# Sed in place replacement given a range of location

Tags: string, sed, replace

I have a text file like

```
Firstline
Sometext1 randomtext1
Sometext2 randomtext2
Sometext3 randomtext3
Sometext4 randomtext4
.
.
.
lastline
```

Expected output

```
Firstline
Sometext1 commontext
Sometext2 commontext
Sometext3 commontext
Sometext4 commontext
.
.
.
lastline
```

Excluding first and last line, for all lines for a location range like location10 to location 20, I have common text to be replaced in this range

How to achieve this using sed in place replacement?

currently I am taking all lines except first and last Into a file, on this file  I'm running awk gsub(start location, offset)
I am passing filename as argument to the script

```
cp $1 $1_original
sed '1d;$d' $1 > output_interim.txt;
awk '{gsub (substr($0,10,10),"commontext",$0); print $0 }' output_interim.txt > output.txt;
(head -1 $1_original; cat output.txt; tail -1 $1_original) > $1;
```

Comment: What efforts did you do on this question? Have a look at [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Adrian, currently I am taking all lines except first and last Into a file, on this file  I'm running awk gsub(start location, offset) , this has additional overhead of creating/removing temporary files

Comment: Then please update your question with your existing solution. It helps other to figure out what exactly you want to achieve and what problems you are having with it. If your problem is the space or performance impact of creating intermediate files, then may be there is a solution with a pipe?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming GNU sed (for `-r` option)

Here, I'm replacing "location11" to "location17" with the text "common" -- save the first 10 characters and replace the next 6 characters:

```
sed -r '1n; $n; s/^(.{10}).{6}/\1common/' <<END
Firstline
Sometext1 randomtext1
Sometext2 randomtext2
Sometext3 randomtext3
Sometext4 randomtext4
.
.
.
lastline
END
```

```
Firstline
Sometext1 commontext1
Sometext2 commontext2
Sometext3 commontext3
Sometext4 commontext4
.
.
.
lastline
```

Then, to write in-place with a backup copy, add the `-i.bak` option to sed.

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks,my strings are not limited, let me make it clear, in each line from start location to end location, I have to replace with a common string

Comment: Still not clear. What are "start location" and "end location"? Please edit your question to provide details. Also, provide the desired output.

Comment: currently I am taking all lines except first and last Into a file, on this file I'm running awk gsub(start location, offset) , this has additional overhead of creating/removing temporary files, regarding location 10 to location 20 , position is the correct word, in abcde, location 2 to location 5 will be 'bcd'